# irregular texture pattern in the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gltf

I have imported a Gltf file into blender. I setup a sun light and rendered it with eevee. it works absolutely fine when rendered with eevee, but in cycles some part of the plane becomes dull with a different intensity.

[image: image thats rendered with black parts in between]
Image rendered with black parts.

[image: This is the material that is applied]
Material configuration

Comment: maybe in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: @moonboots it was not enabled. Sculpt Mask Data was enbable. I have cleared it, still the render has irregular texture pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link to your GLTF file is not helping so much because we don't know what settings you used to import it. So I imported it with the default settings.

After that I saw the same pattern, I selected a front face and deleted it, there was another one and so on - the front side had 6 layers of faces overlapping in the same place as suspected.

To avoid this, you should enable the option *Merge Vertices* when importing the file. In this case Blender checks if there are multiple vertices/faces in the same location and merges them.

[image: merge vertices]

Comment: Hi thank you very much its working now. with merge vertices while importing. I am very new to blender. Gltf was prepared from three js scene using Gltf exporter. I dont know why it created muliple faces while exporting. While creating three Geometry i have created only 2 faces per side of the cuboid. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your mesh has faces overlaying on top of each other, some times duplicates causes render errors like that

Comment: it was simple cube. and it did not had any over lapping meshes

Comment: @BoyapatiRaviKumar First of all, your screenshot doesn't show a cube so what are we seeing there? And secondly, well that this pattern appears in _Cycles_ but not in _Eevee_ is a very strong indication that it's possibly overlapping. You said it's an imported GLTF file - why do you need to import a simple cube? Are you sure it was a simple cube?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Below is the gltf content. The poroblem exists for some of other meshes as well. i have deleted and kept only one mesh for reference.


[link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wwa024fll5enmed/blender_query.gltf/file)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann while checking i have created another cube with similar dimensions. it was looking fine in cycles as well

Comment: @BoyapatiRaviKumar I checked your file (see my answer) and I don't know why you are so sure there are no overlapping faces - because there are. A lot. So downvoting Roger's answer just because you don't know it's correct is not a fair move.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i did not downvote i dont have enough reputation to downvote or upvote. Thank you very much anyways